# "bis / dass die Schwarte kracht”: Wieso kracht die Schwarte sprichwörtlich?

Tags: etymology

**Hypothese**: Irgendwie wird die Redensart adv. *bis die Schwarte kracht* (bis zum Abwinken, bis der Arzt kommt, bis es knallt, *ad absurdum*, insb. ““bis zur Erschöpfung; bis zum Überdruss; übermäßig; in großen Mengen; gewaltig” [redensarten-index]) doch wohl von niederländisch *zwaartekracht* “Schwerkraft" kommen. Eine sinvolle Erklärung dafür sehe ich nicht, doch wie könnte es anders sein?

**Vorbetrachtung**: 1. Lautsymbolik im Hinterglied – Theoretisch kommt erschwerend hinzu, dass *krachen* einerseits wie nl. *kraken*, en. *crack* auf eine Schalwurzel zurückgeführt wird, jedoch nicht ohne außergermanische Vergleiche. Siehe z.B. auch als Scherzname *Volker Racho* "Vollkaracho" (der Endung nach wohl italiänisch oder spanisch).

Andererseits ist *Kraft* nicht weniger abstrakt, ermangelt jedoch weiterer Vergleiche (lt. Pfeifer “eine Labialerweiterung ie. **grep-* der Wurzel ie. **ger-* ‘drehen, winden’” hat wenig für sich und macht keinen Unterschied im Hinblick auf “die unterschiedlichen Erweiterungen der Schallwurzel ie. **ger-* bzw. **grā-* ‘heiser schreien’).

Für althochdeutsch heißt es bei Pfeifer: "Rechtssprachlich bedeutet bereits ahd. *kraft* ‘Gültigkeit, Wirksamkeit’; daran anknüpfend vgl. *rechtskräftig* sowie *in Kraft treten, sein, bleiben, außer Kraft setzen, treten, bleiben*.”

Genügt dies, um auf vb. *greifen* in verschiedenen Wendungen aus der Rechtssprache zu schließen? Bspw. DRW: *ergreifen* VI “(Rechtskraft) erlangen”, *vnd ergreifft also das ergangen vrteil seine krafft* 1561 Rotschitz Bl. 75 Vermutlich nicht, da ausweislich DRW: *greifen* A transitiv I eine Person 1 “(mit den Händen) fassen, ergreifen” bzw. III bildlich 1. “(Krieg) beginnen”, “(einen Rat) fassen” ein handfester Bedeutungsunterschied begriffen wird. Von *kriegen* steht an der Stelle nichts, fr. *guerre* “Krieg" ebensowenig, während *angreifen* und *ergreifen* wie *anfangen*, *anfechten*, *klagen*, *sich beschweren* etc. hier zu weit ins Feld führen.

Höchstwahrscheinlich ließen sich alternative Formulierungen finden, etwa *knacken*.

2. Zum Vordergleid – *Schwere*, nl. *zwaarte* "het zwaar sijn" < *zwaar* is jedenfals nicht mit *schwarze Magie* zu vergleichen. *Zum Schwert greifen*, vgl. nl. *zwaard*, *grijpen*, ist dem vorhergesagten nach auszuschließen, zumal *Schwert* auch unsicher ist. Leider ist “Verdere herkomst onzeker”, nachdem Pokorny **wer-* mit s-mobile nur andeutet (Philippa *et al.*, vgl. Pfeifer). Meines Wissens ist *sehr* mit *sever* zu vergleichen, etwa "du bist schwer in Ordnung", und umgekehrt *schwer* mit *serious*.

Demgegenüber ist *Schwarte*, nl. *zwoord*, jedoch auch “Herkunft ungewiss” (Pfeifer). *Schwarte* wird zwar vereinzelt auch noch als Synonym zu *Schinken* “dickes Buch” begriffen, ist für die Redewendung kaum maßgeblich da Bücher in der Regel keinen Krach machen. Dass *Schweinsschwarte* nach längerem braten kross wird, halte ich auch für unerheblich, selbst wenn über den Begriff der Lederhaut wiederum auf *cortex* "Rinde" bzw. *codex* "Buch, Baumstumpf", *cutis* "Rinde, Haut" geschlossen werden könnte.

Mit einer solchen Unterscheidung würde der Vergleich zum Niederländisch unbegründeter Weise ignoriert.

*Last but not least* ist es wohl Zufall, dass sich *gravy* zu *gravity* verhält wie *Schwarte* zu einer *schweren* Kost, einem *herzhaften* Essen, *kräftig* gewürzt. Die lautmalerische Note wird daran besonders deutlich.

3. Wahrscheinlicher erscheint mir ein Ansatz mit σαρκ "Fleisch" einerseits und *Geschwader* andererseits, angenommen *square* wie *Quader* ließe hier eine Rückführung auf **kʷetwóres* zu und, insofern diese Form als unnatürliches Konstrukt der vergleichenden Methode zu genügen herhalten muss, ferner einen Zusammenhang mit **kʷékʷlos* (vgl. *wheel*) bzw. **Kers-* (vgl. *Karren*) zu vermuten. Die Doppeldeutigkeit diesen Über- und Nebeneinanders erscheint mir bisher unüberwindbar.

**Schluss**: Das würde im Ergebnis bedeuten, auf deutscher Seite sei für die Redensart *bis die Schwarte Kracht* mit mindestens einer von drei Möglichkleiten zu rechnen, abgesehen von der Null-Hypothese, dass keinerlei Verwandschaft vorliegt (auch dies wäre angemessen zu begründen): a) *Schwert*, *greifen*, insoweit unbegründet und auszuschließen, b) eine übetragene Bedeutung mit *kraft* als Verb, das insofern nicht ersichtlich ist und in *kriegen* zu suchen wäre, was wiederum lautliche Severitäten bereitet, c) *Achse* in einem technologischen Sinne; beheflsweise auf Bootsbau zu übertragen.

Ein vermeinicher Hinweis darauf findet sich lediglich unter **wer-* s.v. *zwaar* zur Wurzel, “ die in het Germaans verder alleen in oe. *weorn*, *wearn* ‘schaar, troep’ […] voorkomt.” Behelfsweise sei auf nl. *waagen* "Ladung" als Ableitung vom Fortbewegungsmittel genannt. Außerdem denkbar wäre gleichzusetzen *Vierkant* als Prügel wie die Kline eines Degen, quasi Schwertes; s.a. *Scharte, to card*; bzw. *Schaar* anstatt *Geschwader, Schwadron*. Außerdem wird im albanischen eine Ableitung "Drehspieß” quasi Lammkeule aus **kʷel-* vermutet. Der Wechsel *l ~ r* ist im deutschen jedoch recht selten.

https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=schwarte&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&sp0=rart_ou&sp1=rart_varianten_ou

https://etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/zwaartekracht

https://etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/kracht

https://etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/zwaar

https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/krachen

https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Kraft

https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/schweer

https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Schwarte

https://drw.hadw-bw.de/drw-cgi/zeige?index=lemmata&term=*greifen

Answer (score 1):

Die Schwarte kracht auch wortwörtlich - wenn man sie schön knusprig in der Pfanne oder im Ofen brät bis sie kross wird und (krachend) aufplatzt.

Dieser wortwörtliche Ursprung, im Sinne dass etwas Schönes und früher auch eher Seltenes (ein Krustenbraten) bis zur Vollendung (perfekt gegart mit aufgeplatzter, krosser Schwarte/Fettschicht) gebracht wird, wird in dieser Redensart aufgegriffen und übertragen oder als pars pro toto gebraucht.

Comment: Stichwort "Krustenbraten" bei dem die Haut und die Fettschicht darunter (zusammem "Schwarte") wie Popcorn bei genügend Hitze aufspringt und dadurch erst wirklich essbar wird. Vorher ist die Schwarte zäh und dick, danach knusprig und brüchig.

Comment: Das ist sehr spekulativ. Die Schwarte steht hier für etwas Schöne, das bis zur Vollendung gebracht wird. Die Redewendung "bis die Schwarte kracht " steht allerdings auch für Negatives, vgl. https://www.dwds.de/wb/bis%20die%20Schwarte%20kracht.

Answer (score 1):

Mehrere ältere Wörterbücher deuten darauf hin, dass *bis die Schwarte Kracht* unter anderem von Prügel, Schlägen usw. gesagt wird. In dieser Hinsicht ist es durchaus sinnvoll, dass *Schwarte* "Haut" und damit aufplatzende Hautverletzungen, Platzwunden, gemeint sein könnten.

Leider erklärt das nicht, weshalb und wieso *krachen* darin Eingang findet.

Comment: Das schnelle Zusammentreffen von Gürtel und Haut kann durchaus ein krachendes Geräusch verursachen...

Comment: würde ich so nicht sagen. Auf English ist es die whip (Peitsche) die crack makt, bzw der cracker der die Peitsche schwingt. Vielleicht ist dabei von crank auszugehen, bzw. schr-irgendwas. Bis der Schwarte schreit.